# AttributeError with django.setup()

Tags: django

I am trying to create a population script following [the instructions in the Tango with Django book](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/models.html#creating-a-population-script). The script is sited in the project root folder and starts with these lines:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'pyguess.settings')
import django
django.setup()
```

But it fails to run, returning this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/desousa/djcode/pyguess/populate_core.py", line 5, in <module>
    django.setup()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setup'
```

What is going wrong here? Is the `import django` instruction failing somehow?

Comment: are you using the same version of Django as the book?

Comment: As kedar said. `setup` wasn't added until 1.7, so this won't work in any pre-1.7 versions. Run `python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"` to print the version number.

Comment: That was it, I had version 1.6.1 installed on this system. Could you please file an answer? Include the command: `sudo pip uninstall Django && sudo pip install Django==1.7.6`.