# Can't execute independent python script

Tags: python, django, production-environment

In my development environment I can execute python scripts using following header:

```
import os, django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
django.setup()
# Then the actual body...
```

Now in my production environment, which is set up in a `virtualenv` I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myname/myproject/myscript.py", line 3, in <module>
    django.setup()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setup'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have any **`django.py`** file in that folder?

Comment: Do you mean in the production environment? No.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: check both versions of django: dev & prod

Comment: On production `1.8.6`.

Comment: @Saphire see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279230/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-setup-cant-run-development and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101057/attributeerror-with-django-setup#comment46432922_29101057

Comment: On my development environment I have `1.8.4`. Ok. So what should I do? Just upgrade my local django?

Comment: I gues you don't have 1.8.x in prod

Comment: Are you sure that your app is using the virtualenv? and the virtualenv has the correct django version? 1.8.x

Comment: @Robert No I am not sure If my app uses the virtualenv. How can I make my app use it?

Comment: @Saphire, there are a lot of ways. But a general rule is that you need to run the python interpreter that is inside the virtualenv. i.e. /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python ....